# Show revenue per single page in DFP Small Business

Tags: google-dfp

I would like to implement DFP on a website in such a way that I can generate a report that tells me how much revenue was generated per single page.

Let's use an example to make it clear:
Imagine a blogging website. It has a main page and each blog entry is a separate page. New blog entries can also be created. The website uses DFP to display ads.

I want to create a report where I can see for each blog entry how much revenue it generated. Unfortunately I couldn't find an option to do just that. How can I achieve that goal?

Comment: It might be difficult if you are not using Adsense or Google Adx to get the revenu displayed easily. Could you precise the sources of revenue ?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple options.
It's not a general solution and can not be very handy if you have thousands of pages, but it might work for a smaller blog.

1. Use a dedicated placement consisting of several adunits for every page or at least those that need to be counted separately
2. Use [key values](https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/177381?hl=en) and create [reports](https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/3108447?hl=en) split by them. On your pages you can generate key/values dynamically like article_id={{ article_id }}, on DFP's end you'll need to type in all the articles you have or need to track in one place
3. 1 and 2, but not per individual page but per section of the site to have smaller (=manageable) number of ad units/key values. Of course if such a granularity fits your business needs